# SQL while loop from select statement to insert values

Tags: sql-server

New to high level SQL stuff.

Want to make it so that a select statement will fill in values 7 times then move onto the next row.

EXAMPLE:

```
X | Y
A   1
A   2
....
A   7
B   1
B   2
....
```

This is some code that I have.

```
WHILE (*select that queries letters of unique value*) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO table1 (X,Y) *select that queries letters of unique value*,1
     INSERT INTO table1 (X,Y) *select that queries letters of unique value*,2
     ....
     INSERT INTO table1 (X,Y) *select that queries letters of unique value*,7
END
```

Would love some help. Thanks!

Comment: I would urge you to read your post and ask yourself if you think you would be able to provide an answer having only the information in the post. And not sure why you think you need a loop here....I am 100% certain you can do this set based. Here is a great place to get some ideas of how to make this question answerable. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way too:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 'A' AS VAL1
    UNION
    SELECT 'B'
) A
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 AS VAL2
    UNION
    SELECT 2
    UNION
    SELECT 3
    UNION 
    SELECT 4
    UNION
    SELECT 5
    UNION
    SELECT 6
    UNION
    SELECT 7
) B
ORDER BY A.VAL1
```

You can also do like:

```
CROSS JOIN
(
    VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)
) B (VAL2)
ORDER BY A.VAL1
```

There is no need to use a loop, you can directly insert those values to your table like:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (X, Y)
SELECT A.VAL1, B.VAL2
FROM...
```